# how can i make peer review before publication?

Tags: review-articles

How can i get peer review of my research before submission to Journal of Dental Research 
Osseous Reaction to Three Different Capping Materials : Experimental Study

Comment: That you need to ask this question in this forum might mean something is really wrong..

Answer (score 2):

Two options:
You show it to your peers or colleagues and get their feedback, or

You submit to a journal who will send it out to review if they don't reject it "of the desk".